# How to change the url for Home and Dashboard buttons in Rails admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-admin

Is there any configuration to change the default URL for home and dashboard buttons in rails admin (top navigation) ?

I did some thins like this but it didn't work:

```
config.actions do
    dashboard do
       %{<a href="#{www.stackoverflow.com}">Download</a>}.html_safe
    end                  
end
```

Comment: It takes the `root_path`, refer this and comments there to define multiple root paths based on user type.. http://minhajuddin.com/2011/10/24/how-to-change-the-rails-root-url-based-on-the-user-or-role/

Comment: @peter no This can not be helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can download the layout files separately here: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/tree/master/app/views/layouts/rails_admin

Put them inside `app/views/layouts/rails_admin` and apply your changes.

Comment: I did this and when I redirect to /admin it shows me the github page ! not the admin panel!

Comment: Please make sure to share as much code as possible that relates to this problem.